# Domain class variables

Tags: grails, groovy, metaprogramming

How do domain classes in Grails have variables like `static constraints ={ }`?

I can't see any direct inheritance.

I guess it's meta-programming but can you explain this?

Comment: Hey there. I tried to clarify what you mean in a proper grammar, it was very confusing to read. If you see any mistake, please edit your question and correct it carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Grails domain classes don't extend a framework-provided base class, this is consistent with how persistent entities work in Hibernate.

Also be aware that static methods don't get inherited anyway, and no fields get inherited. The mapping and constraints variables are static fields declared on the domain class. Inheritance doesn't apply here.

Grails knows which classes are domain classes, services, controllers, etc. based on where their files are in the project structure. Grails knows to look for static variables in the domain objects named constraints and mapping.

This much is leveraging of conventions, not meta-programming. Meta-programming would be involved in implementing the DSL for the entries in those closures, and in adding GORM methods to the domain classes.

Comment: Ok that makes sense but those certain operations these static variable do needs to happen somewhere. So are domain class or controllers, compiled separately in a different manner. Can you explain the process in more detail ?? Also can I add similar variables and if yes how ????